# structs inside classes

Tags: c++, class, struct, member

I have some doubts about the syntax for having structs as members of classes.

I have this struct:

```
/*  POS.H   */
#ifndef POS_H
#define POS_H
struct pos{
    int x;
    int y;

    pos operator=(const pos& a){
        x=a.x;  y=a.y;
        return a;
    }

    pos operator+(const pos& a)const {
        return (pos){a.x+x,a.y+y};
    }

    bool operator==(const pos& a)const {
        return (a.x==x && a.y== y);
    }
};
#endif /* POS_H */
```

and in another file there is the main function:

```
/* MAIN.CPP */
#include "pos.h"
#include "clase.h"
int main(){
    pos pos;
    pos.x=0;
    pos.y=0;
    clase clase();
}
```

Then there are 3 different contents for the file clase.h which contains the class clase.

This compiles fine:

```
#include "pos.h"
class clase{
    private:
        pos posi;
    public:
        clase(pos pos):posi(pos){};
};
```

This does not compile(just changing the name of the member):

```
#include "pos.h"
class clase{
    private:
        pos pos;
    public:
        clase(pos pos):pos(pos){};
```

This also compiles fine(using pos as neme but using the keyword struct):

```
#include "pos.h"
class clase{
    private:
        struct pos pos;
    public:
        clase(struct pos pos):pos(pos){};
};
```

My question is: **why these codes compile or do not?**

Comment: Because the name of the member is the same as the type (both are `pos`). That won't work.

Comment: This is not doing what you think `clase clase();` This is forward declaration of a function. What you probably meant is `clase clase;`

Comment: To close voter: The answer might not have much practical value, but it is still a simple objective question about the language rules, something that anyone working on compilers, refactoring tools, etc would need to look into.

Comment: As a side note. I personally use a naming convention so it is easy to spot types from variables/functions. Which also goes a way to solving this type of confusion.

Comment: @BenVoigt +1 on issue of close vote. this is a simple technical question.

Comment: @user1754322 Is the question: _Why can the name of a member be identical to its type only if I add the keyword `struct`?_ If this is the question, what do the operators, data members and the main function have to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's traditionally not good coding practice to name a member the same as the struct name, looks like the compiler is getting confused when you try to declare a private member named pos unless you enforce the struct type.

In short it's just naming conflicts, you should get in the habit of naming members slightly differently than the struct or object name.  Perhaps name your structs and objects in TitleCase and then use camelCasing on your members.  In this example name the struct POS and then in clase private: POS mPos;

Comment: Ok, but the curious thing is that the compiler allows to have the same name for the struct and the the variable inside the main fuction and it does not in the case it is a member of a class

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know exactly why it's a problem but it is sometimes.  I don't mean to force the "just do as I say" answer but it is just a better idea to use a coding convention that will somehow make member naming and struct / object naming always be different to keep from ever encountering this issue in the first place.